# Using a simple language model in Sphinx-4

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I've learned the basics of how to use Shpinx-4 as a speech recognition Toolkit.

I've wrote number of sentences to build the language model for my small project(As a start 10 sentences) to train since the performance of the SR was not very good for my question.

Then I did upload it to: http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html

I mainly read this http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm to learn how to create a language model.

- Now, What shall I do next to use it?
- and can I still use the en-us.lm.dmp language model?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, What shall I do next to use it?

You can specify it in your source code a for [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) as

```
configuration.setLanguageModelPath("file:<path_to_your_new_model>");
```

In that case your new language model will be loaded and used for recognition

> and can I still use the en-us.lm.dmp language model?

You can switch between them in runtime.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, How can I switch between them in runtime?

Comment: See Dialog demo in sources